# How to send variables between a sheet and book?

Tags: excel, vba

Ultimately, I'm trying to highlight cells when focus moves away from a workbook.

Here's my code (In `ThisWorkbook`):

```
Public s As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    s = Selection
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    s.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    s.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    s.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    s.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 204, 204)  ' Blue
End Sub
```

But I'm getting an error on the first `s.Interior.ColorIndex` encountered:

> `Object variable or With block variable not set`

---

Here's some images of my env:

**Sheet1**
[image: Sheet1]

**ThisWorkbook** (Error highlighted):
[image]

Comment: `s = Selection`  ==> `Set s = Selection`, although `Set s = Target` would also work.

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried `Set s = Selection` and got `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` same as before.

Comment: *Where* are these modules? I copied your code: 1) the public `s` declaration in a standard code module, 2) the `selection_change` in a worksheet module, and 3) the `activate`/`deactivate` in the workbook module -- and they all work for me (after using `Set`). My guess is that you are not using `Option Explicit`. Public variables should be declared in standard code modules. If not, the variable `s` won't be visible in the `workbook` module.

Comment: If you first open the workbook `Activate` will trigger before `SelectionChange`, hence you will get a runtime error since `s` will still be nothing. That is one of the problems that the last part of my answer is designed to address.

Comment: @JohnColeman [and Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryIBc.png). Edit (after reading your last comment): OH, OK! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1) In order to be visible throughout the project, Public variable declarations must be in a standard code module. Thus the line

```
Public s As Range
```

shouldn't be in `ThisWorkbook` but should be in a standard code module.

2) `s = Selection` should be changed to `Set s = Selection`

3) The sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set s = Selection
End Sub
```

Should be in a sheet module (and repeated for every sheet that you want this for). It isn't a syntax error to have it in `ThisWorkbook`, but it won't work as intended.

4) It is dangerous to assume that `s` is defined whenever the `activate` or `deactivate` is triggered. You should guard against that. Something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If s Is Nothing Then
        Set s = Selection
        Exit Sub
    End If
    s.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    s.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 204, 204)  ' Blue
End Sub
```

With something similar for `Deactivate`.

Comment: FWIW - if `s` was declared `Public` in the code module of a sheet which has a code name of `Sheet1` (not the worksheet `.Name`, the actual code name), then it can be accessed from other modules within the project as `Sheet1.s`.  But this would be highly **NOT** recommended (at least be me) so the idea of placing it in a standard code module is better.